# Managing files using Visual Basic for application

Tags: excel, file-management, vba

I have some files hyperlinked in Excel. Can I have a VBA code to manage these files using their hyperlinked address? For example, moving a file from one folder to another both hyperlinked.
Any thoughts?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  You can take the [tour] first and learn [ask] a good question and create a [mcve].  That makes it easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your asking, but if you want to move a file, it's very simple and easy and you could have found this on the internet.

Look into this website for more information: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2t00swhw.aspx

How I would move a file(according to msdn)

> My.Computer.FileSystem.MoveFile("C:\Folder1\arg1.txt",
>   "C:\Folder1\arg2.txt")

The first argument would be the directory you have the file in, the second, is the one you want move it to.